# How python [internally] retrieves elements from array and finds minimum

Tags: python, arrays

For this question http://www.spoj.com/problems/ACPC10D/ on SPOJ, I wrote a python solution as below:

```
count = 1
while True:
    no_rows = int(raw_input())

    if no_rows == 0:
        break

    grid = [[None for x in range(3)] for y in range(2)]

    input_arr = map(int, raw_input().split())

    grid[0][0] = 10000000
    grid[0][1] = input_arr[1]
    grid[0][2] = input_arr[1] + input_arr[2]

    r = 1
    for i in range(0, no_rows-1):
        input_arr = map(int, raw_input().split())
        _r = r ^ 1
        grid[r][0] = input_arr[0] + min(grid[_r][0], grid[_r][1])
        grid[r][1] = input_arr[1] + min(min(grid[_r][0], grid[r][0]), min(grid[_r][1], grid[_r][2]))
        grid[r][2] = input_arr[2] + min(min(grid[_r][1], grid[r][1]), grid[_r][2])


        r = _r

        print str(count) + ". " + str(grid[(no_rows -1) & 1][1])

        count += 1
```

The above code exceeds time limit. However, when I change the line

```
grid[r][2] = input_arr[2] + min(min(grid[_r][1], grid[r][1]), grid[_r][2])
```

to

```
grid[r][2] = input_arr[2] + min(min(grid[_r][1], grid[_r][2]), grid[r][1])
```

the solution is accepted. If you notice the difference, the first line compares, `grid[_r][1], grid[r][1]` for minimum (`i.e. the row number are different`) and second line compares `grid[_r][1], grid[_r][2]` for minimum(`i.e. the row number are same`)

This is a consistent behaviour. I want to understand, how python is processing those two lines - so that one results in exceeding time limit, while other is fine.

Comment: Why are you nesting `min()` calls, `min()` can take multiple arguments, e.g. `min(grid[_r][1], grid[_r][2], grid[r][1])`?

Comment: I agree to that, but I want to understand - what could probably be happening in the way I've coded. How the two lines differ so much that one results in TLE <time limit exceeded>

Comment: Sounds to me like your solution is on the edge of acceptable runtime, and it just happened to run a bit faster due to completely unrelated factors (perhaps total machine workload or something) when you tried it with the arguments switched around.

Comment: I that case, it shouldn't have been a consistent behaviour. I tried the TLE solution for more than 5-6 times, and it is consistently TLE, while the one that was accepted, is always accepted.